# Product Classification Parent/Child Hierarchy - "A parent attribute must be related to the key attribute of the dimension."

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, ssas-2012

This is my first post on stackoverflow... I did some searching and could not find my answer, so I will ask here.

I have a need to report sales by Product Classification.

- FactTransactions have a reference to ProductID
- My DimProduct table has ProductID, ClassID, ProductName, ...
- My DimProductClass table has ClassID, ParentClassId, ClassName,...
- Product Classification is a parent child relationship... one to many

A Product can belong to a single class (one to many), but enter the hierarchy at different levels... for example:

1. Pipe A (Product) -> Galvanized Pipe (Class) -> Pipe (Class)
2. Pipe B (Product) -> Steel Pipe (Class) -> Pipe (Class)
3. Pipe C (Product) -> Pipe (Class)
4. Pipe D (Product) -> Galvanized Pipe (Class) -> Pipe (Class)

In SSAS, I have taken the following steps:

1. Defined my relationships in the data source view

   - Related Fact (f) to DimProduct (p)
   - Related DimProduct (p) to DimProductCategory (pc1) on p.ClassID = pc1.ClassID
   - Related DimProductCategory (pc1) to DimProductCategory (pc2) on pc1.ParentClassId = pc2.ClassId
2. Defined a product dimension

   - Pulled in the following attributes

     - ProductName (ProductID Key Column; Key Field Attribute Usage)
     - ClassName (ClassID Key Column)
     - Classes (ParentClassID key column, Parent Attribute Usage)
   - Related Attributes

     - ProductName -> ClassName
     - ClassName -> Classes

When I do the last step, I get an error **"A parent attribute must be related to the key attribute of the dimension."**

Here is a link to a screenshot of a similar mock up using AdventureWorks (I don't have enough reputation points to add a screenshot):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXY6Q.png

What can I do to roll up the product transactions into their necessary product classifications?

Thanks,

BPlantes

Comment: It is not clear how do you have designed parent-child relationship in Classes dimension.(Why relation has been built using ParentClassID column?)
It would be much easier to understand your issue if you give us a screenshot of the data source view.

Comment: Dalex... I just added a link to a screenshot of a similar DSV in Adventure works.

Comment: like error says, parent id should be a key attribute for the dimension. So you should add parent-child relations table as separate dimension. You cannot include classes into product. Only one possible hierarchy inside of the Product table can be something like ProductID->ParentProductID.